# WPF: Get pixel under using VB.NET (not using GDI)

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I am working on a WPF application and I am looking to retrieve the color value of a pixel on the screen (the screen being the Window that my application is displaying).

I have found a tutorial that shows how to do this using the gdi32 API but since this is a WPF application I am looking for a way to do this without using GDI.

I have also found an example of how to retrieve a pixel from within a picture using a CroppedBitmap; however, I'm not using an image in my application.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: I assume you mean outside your app.

Comment: Nope, I'm talking about within my application. I am trying to get the color values of the pixel next to the mouse within a defined area (which happens to be a Canvas) in my WPF application.

Answer (score 1):

**Full Disclosure: I have contributed to the WriteableBitmapEx open source project, however it is not my library nor am I affiliated with its owner**

The only way that I know to do this in vanilla WPF is to use RenderTargetBitmap to render the canvas to a bitmap, then use the WriteableBitmap API to get a pointer to the pixel in question. This will be a very slow operation as the render operation involves creation of a temporary (software) surface, however it would be suitable for infrequent operations, such as paint "color picker" type applications.

Also see the [WriteableBitmapEx](http://WriteableBitmapEx.codeplex.com) library, as this has functions for GetPixel and SetPixel which will help you in this example.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will have to check this out for my own curiosity. I ended up using one of the new Telerik controls in my main application but I think your solution will work...never thought of serializing the canvas to a bitmap in order to use the cropping technique :) I'll check it out when I have time to return to that project!

Comment: heh, I'm a hacker at heart ;) 
Telerik make some great stuff, I've used their libraries before in commercial apps and rate them for being lightweight / performant.